Maplibre terrain doesn't work in a next app
We have a maplibre map we have been using and I tried to add a 3D terrain but it doesn't work. We use the react-map-gl library and I formatted to the terrain according to the example given by the docs.
 <Map
   style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
   initialViewState={initialViewport}
   mapStyle={mapStyle as any}
   {...viewport}
   terrain={{
     source: "terrainSource",
     exaggeration: 1,
   }}
 >
   <Source
     id="terrainSource"
     type="raster-dem"
     url="http://localhost:4000/tiles.json"
     tileSize={512}
     maxzoom={18}
     encoding="terrarium"
   />
 </Map>

Creating a hillshade layer using the same source and the URL works just fine, but I don't even see the requests being sent for the terrain.
I just added the parts that I think is relevant.
viewport variable only contains zoom and center information.
